# lookup field in ModelViewSet django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an users endpoint in drf.
I want the `lookup_field` for retrieving user to be something like `@username` not `username`.
How can I implement this?

Comment: `If you want to use object lookups other than pk, set 'lookup_field'. For more complex lookup requirements override get_object()` - DRF source

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have the `get_object()` source link ? @Kedar

Comment: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py#L75 - strip `@` from `self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just solved it by creating a custom router.
in `routers.py`:

```
from rest_framework.routers import Route, SimpleRouter


class UserRouter(SimpleRouter):
    """
    A router for user to support @username lookup.
    """
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create',
            },
            name='{basename}-list',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/@{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy'
            },
            name='{basename}-detail',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
        ),
    ]
```

then in `urls.py`:

```
from .routers import UserRouter
from .apis import UserViewSet
from django.urls import path, include


router = UserRouter()

router.register("", UserViewSet, basename="user")

urlpatterns = [
    path("/", include(router.urls)),    
]
```

now you can get user with `@username` lookup for example in my case:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/accounts/@mojixcoder/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_user_model()
>>> Users = User.objects.all()
>>> users_list = list()
>>> for user in Users:       
...   tmp = '@' + str(user) 
...   users_list.append(tmp)
>>> users_list
['@a', '@admin', '@test23', '@test24']
```

You can put this code line by line in your view,

if you are using DRF then just return users_list as response

```
return Response(users_list, {"Message": f"users list"}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

For filtering the users_list on the frontend and making it more interactive;

- VanillaJS add event listener to the lookup field. Filter the result.
- React, add a two states one for your results users, the other for lookup input,

quick bruteforce search algorthim I can think of is this:
**keep in mind this is slow !**

```
handleFindUser = (users, searchedUser) => {
        let sr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            if(users[i].includes(searchedUser)) {
                sr.push( users[i].username, searchedUser)
            };
        };
        }, 1000)
       return sr;
    };
```

**[EDIT]**
Docs
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/
Filter users by url:]

in api/views/

```
class UsersLookup(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = Users

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Users.objects.filter(User__username=username)
```

in api/urls.py

```
re_path('^users/(?P@<username>.+)/$', UsersLookup.as_view()),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't want to loop through all users. I want my lookup field to be something like this `/users/@username` instead of `/users/username`